# AWS Amplify throwing SerializationException when trying to login

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-mobilehub

I have a react native project which is connected to AWS mobilehub with AWS amplify. I have done all the configuration with `mobilehub configure` and pulled all the settings from aws using `mobilehub pull`

Register works perfectly fine. I am able to register user and get confirmation using

```
let resp = await Auth.signUp({
    username,
    password
});
```

However for some bizarre reason, when I use `signIn` function with exactly the same parameters, I get `SerializationException`

```
let resp = await Auth.signIn({
    username,
    password
});
```

The error I get is as below

```
7:34:24 PM: Object {
7:34:24 PM:   "code": "SerializationException",
7:34:24 PM:   "message": "Start of structure or map found where not expected.",
7:34:24 PM:   "name": "SerializationException",
7:34:24 PM: }
```

How do I resolve this? There is no documentation anywhere on what this error is saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ran into this myself - you want to pass in username and password as separate arguments to Auth.signIn, not as values in an object.

`Auth.signIn(username, password)`

Hope that helps!

Comment: perfect. I must be blind